# C and casting - why does this program stop at 6?

Tags: c, casting

I edited a C program for my assignment, previously there wasn't typecasting and the iteration stopped at i=1, now with the typecasting it stops at i=6.

Any ideas why? Thanks in advance!

```
int main(void)
{

    int i = 0;
    double d = 0.0;

    while ( (i == (int) (d * 10)) && (i < 10) )
    {
        i = i + 1;
        d = (double) (d + 0.1);
        printf("%d %lf\n", i, d);
    }

    printf("%d %lf\n", i, d);

    getch();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please edit and provide a meaningful title, it makes it easier to navigate.

Comment: @Kos done. It's a shame that people don't read what they are typing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has been stated many times before, the reason this doesn't work is that binary floating point numbers cannot represent all decimal floating point binary numbers, it just isn't possible. To read more, check out this really great article:

[What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://floating-point-gui.de)

Now, on the more practical side of things, when using floating point and comparing it to another number, you should almost always `round` the value or use an epsilon value, like this:

```
if (ABS(doubleValue - intValue) < 0.00001) // 0.00001 is a margin-of-error for floating point arithmetic
    // the two numbers are even (or close to it)
```

Comment: In fact, numerical programmers always try to avoid having to use tolerances if at all feasible. The reason is simple. How do you choose your tolerance. By using a tolerance you merely swap one problem for another.

Answer (score 4):

Floating point arithmetic is inexact. The value `0.1` is not exactly representable in binary floating point. The recommended reading here is: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

At some point in the program, `d` becomes slightly less than `i/10` due to rounding error, and so your loop terminates.

Comment: You should probably include how to fix this.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII In order to know how to fix it, one would need to know what the actual goal was.

Comment: Wow that was fast, thanks and sorry for the title and tag mess. The problem is the question is "Identify the source of the problem and make modifications accordingly." So I am not sure what the tutor wanted either. I'd just use a for loop without the d but I don't think that's what they meant.

Comment: I think your tutor is teaching you poorly. If the answer really is to use tolerances then this is a poor example. The right way to deal with the code in the question is exactly as you propose. But yes, I'm sure that's not what the tutor wants. Tolerances have their own problems and every sane numerical programmer avoids them where possible. Anyway, I guess you'll just have to try to get along in the system you are in!

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the other answers, I'd like to answer the question why the loop terminates earlier with the condition `i == (d * 10)` than with `i == (int) (d * 10)`.

In the first case, `int` value at the left side of `==` is promoted to double, so the inequality happens when the accumulated error in `d*10` is either positive or negative (e.g. 0.999999 or 1.000001).

In the 2nd case, the right side is truncated to int, so the inequality happens only when the error is negative (e.g. 5.999999). Therefore, the 1st version would fail earlier.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: The question was: `previously there wasn't typecasting and the iteration stopped at i=1, now with the typecasting it stops at i=6`

Comment: Not really... that was my question. But I think I know what the tutor wanted. It's Richard J. Ross III's answer, I remember it being mentioned in the lecture.